# Can I make sure history logs all execution?

Tags: rhel, command-history, sles

Please forgive the ambiguous nature of this question but I was wondering if there's a way to make sure that all commands executed by some host are logged into history. In my case, if I send a command across a network to a host and it gets executed. When I check the history there is no record of that command. Is this typical behavior/can I change it?

Comment: How exactly do you "send a command across a network to a host"?

Comment: If by history you mean the shell history, that's not likely to work (not least because it's writeable by the user). Maybe `auditd` is interesting for you?

Answer (score 3):

The shell history is maintained for interactive shell sessions (and is trivial to alter or disable); assuming the remote command is done via SSH, the shell need not even be involved given that `sshd` can simply fork and exec the command to run. Solutions would include turning on process accounting (this is global to a system) or using some sort of wrapper for the (presumably) SSH connection that in addition to the fork and exec bit also writes a log of what is being run somewhere.